# Apache Beam KDA application not creating checkpoints

Tags: apache-beam, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have an Apache Beam application deployed on Amazon KDA.

It has checkpointing enabled with the default settings.

```
"FlinkApplicationConfigurationDescription": {
"CheckpointConfigurationDescription": {
"ConfigurationType": "DEFAULT",
"CheckpointingEnabled": true,
"CheckpointInterval": 60000,
"MinPauseBetweenCheckpoints": 5000
},
```

But in the application logs I could see:

> "UnboundedSources present which rely on checkpointing, but
> checkpointing is disabled."

It only checkpoints if I pass `CheckpointInterval` as a runtime property to my application. So is it necessary to pass these values explicitly?

The application basically reads from Kinesis, window data into a fixed duration of size ~ 30s, then publish data back to PubSub.

```
   pipeline
            .apply("Read from Kinesis",  new KinesisIORead())
            .apply("Windowing", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30))))
            .apply(WithKeys.of(DUMMY_KEY))
            .apply(GroupIntoBatches.ofSize(5))
            .apply(Values.create())
            .apply("Map values to single object", ParDo.of(new GroupedMessage()))
            .apply("Write to Pub/Sub", new PubSubWrite()));
```

The application jar includes:

- beam-sdks-java-core:2.31.0
- beam-runners-flink-1.11:2.31.0
- beam-sdks-java-io-kafka:2.31.0

Comment: Where are the "default settings" being set? Maybe they're not getting picked up?

Comment: Checkpointing is enabled from the AWS UI itself

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment` is not picking up changes set in the AWS UI, and hence when calling `getCheckpointConfig().isCheckpointingEnabled()` it claims that checkpointing is not enabled. I would pass these explicitly to make sure it's working correctly.